# Start an external command line process in Java 11

Tags: ubuntu, java-11

I am using a CLI based validation tool to check some image files. It runs on command prompt where commands are like "my_app input_file config_file".  I want to integrate it in a Java application (in Java 11). So i need to run them from my Java project. I tried to start the application from Java by following code :

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            rt.exec(new String[]{"/path/to/external/application/exefile","/c","./my_command -h"});

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But it does not prompt the command line and start the application.
Could anyone tell me how to run the process in Java 11 ?

Update:

My external process is working now. But i got another problem. The process returns some output which i need to check line by line. i need to check whether it shows any invalid errors. in case of invalid errors, i will call another external process. i was trying to use BufferedReader to process the output like below, but it does not show any result.

```
            BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

String s = null;
            while ((s = output.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
```

Comment: Hi @Raz, do you have any arror message or stacktrace ? Also you won't get any prompt if you don't run cmd or another shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind [the documentation of `Runtime.exec(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String%5B%5D)):

> An invocation of the form `exec(cmdarray)` behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation [`exec`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String%5B%5D,java.lang.String%5B%5D,java.io.File))`(cmdarray, null, null)`.

[`exec(cmdarray, null, null)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String%5B%5D,java.lang.String%5B%5D,java.io.File)):

> …
> [`ProcessBuilder.start()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start()) is now the preferred way to start a process with a modified environment.

The problem is that `exec` always creates pipes for the standard I/O that your process must read or write, to communicate with the new process. Only `ProcessBuilder` allows to alter that behavior in the intended way:

```java
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(
    "/path/to/external/application/exefile", "/c", "./my_command -h")
    .inheritIO().start();
```

The crucial part is [`inheritIO()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()), to tell the process builder that the new process should inherit the standard input, output, and error channels, instead of creating pipes, to use the same console as your process.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But i am getting error. it is not getting correct directory. error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "": error=2, No such  directory . anyway, i am using Ubuntu. How to tell process to find the correct directory ?

Comment: When you specify the command as `"/path/to/external/application/exefile"`, it should not depend on the current directory. That empty string in the exception message is suspicious. But anyway, the [API of `ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#method.summary) provides control over any aspect of the subprocess to create. E.g., [`directory(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File)), to set the current working directory.

Comment: my external process is working now. But i got another problem. The process returns some output which i need to check line by line. i need to check whether it shows any invalid errors. in case of invalid errors, i will call another external process. can you tell me how to check the output line by line ? i was trying to use BufferedReader to process the output, but it does not show any result.

Comment: Mind that the `inheritIO()` call was specifically inserted to let the subprocess use the same stdio channels as your process, i.e. the console. If you want to change that, [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO%28%29) says that `inheritIO()` is a short-cut for `.redirectInput(Redirect.INHERIT) .redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT) .redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT)`, in other words, you can also configure each channel differently, e.g. let the subprocess read from the console but write to a pipe that you can read.

Comment: in my case, the subprocess should use the same console. But i need to read the output of the subprocess and check them line by line if they have any invalid error. so how can i read the output ?

Comment: You have to be more specific about “should use the same console”. Assuming that the subprocess should do ordinary reads and writes on the console and writes error messages to stderr, you should use `inheritIO().redirectError(Redirect.PIPE)` and read from [`process.getErrorStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream())

Comment: i am developing a console application. the subprocess is also a console application. so use of inheritIO() is correct. what i need now is to read the output of the subprocess. this line (Process p = new ProcessBuilder(arg1, arg2).inheritIO().start();) is running the subprocess in the same console which is ok. now i need to read the output of the subprocess. but i can't read the output here

Comment: when i run the subprocess, the output is like this                                            "profile should be valid, (lineno: 214)
Found 3 errors
No, the given file is not valid"

Comment: now i need to read this output. i tried OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream(); System.out.println(out.toString()); but it shows "java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream@13969fbe". can you tell me how to read this output ?

Comment: Calling `toString()` on an `OutputStream` gives you the the logic inherited from `Object`, “class name + `"@"` + hexadecimal hash code”. It’s a `NullOutputStream`, because there is no pipe, as the stdout has been configured to be the console. You need `redirectOutput(Redirect.PIPE)` to get a readable stream. Or, since it now boils down to only have input connected to the console, you may use `new ProcessBuilder(…)
.redirectInput​(Redirect.INHERIT) .redirectErrorStream(true).start();` The `redirectErrorStream(true)` makes both, stdout and stderr available in the single `p.getInputStream() `.